# Simplify an activity diagram

Tags: uml, activity-diagram, system-analysis

I'm working on my graduation project which is an online quiz website. now i'm drawing the UML activity diagram but it gets too complex and i can't add more details because at the end it must be printed in the project documentation in A4 papers.
can i split the diagram into multiple diagrams?. and if i did this should i repeat the login/registration actions in the beginning of each diagram?

[image]

Comment: As a side note: you use forks which makes create/update/delete parallel actions. That's probably not what you intend. Also the guards need to be surrounded by `[` and `]`.

Comment: shoud i make it as a decision (option) or there is a better way?

Comment: A decision is your choice ;-) Probably the user would like a loop instead of being logged out directly. And deciding to cancel the login would as well be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use structured activities to form logical groups. You can instantiate these activities as call behavior actions where needed.

Assume you have an activity `Login`

[image]

(the lying 8 is an invention of Enterprise Architect to indicate an embedded diagram; not UML standard)

which looks inside like

[image]

(just very simplified).

Now you can instantiate that like

[image]

where the fork indicates the action is a call behavior.

Adding activity parameters it would even be possible to parametrize these. Just like you would do when calling a function in a programming language.